# AngularJS updating UI element without flickering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've made a site that display a list of progress bars, with each progress bar showing the progress of some backend job.

Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="job in jobs">
  <div id="progressbar">...</div>
</div>
```

I have a $resource for the jobs list and I have an angular controller polling this resource for changes every N seconds. Whenever I poll, the jobs list is updated and consequently the list of progress bars in the frontend flickers. The jobs list from the backend looks like this:

```
[
  {"name": "job1", "completion": 0.6},
  {"name": "job2", "completion": 0.7}
]
```

Does angular have some tricks to prevent the flickering, or do I have to do this differently? I would like to update the completion percentages, but also update the list with new jobs that have been started in the backend.

Comment: Just FYI - adding `<div id="progressbar">` in the `ng-repeat` will create multiple divs with the same **id** (bad). Is there a need for the `id`?

Comment: You're right. This is not the exact code, just something I wrote to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do any polling with Angular.  If your progressbar directives are rendering a value/style based on the value of job.completion then it will update all by itself as you update the object.

Your flickering may be a result of your polling on top of the normal $digest cycle of Angular.

If you are doing it outside of the digest based on async calls elsewhere then you may be able to use something like underscore's `_.throttle()` function to ensure that they are called only once every x milliseconds.

However, simply updating progress bars should not be too taxing - especially if you're animating via CSS and not JS.

If you could share the CSS and the relevant code from your directive that may help narrow it down some more as well.

Comment: Are you saying that I don't need to explicitly do a $scope.jobs = Jobs.query() (Jobs is the $resource) every N seconds? Is angular going to do update the Jobs resource for me? How often?

Comment: If you are setting $scope.jobs = Jobs.query() and it returns an object that you are later updating then, yes, Angular will update the view each time it changes.  Because you are using ng-repeat, Angular automatically sets a $watch on the value of jobs, and again on each property you bind within the ng-repeat.  So if you are doing {{ job.completion }} somewhere it will automatically update the view when Angular detects a change to the value of job.completion.  That is why you must be updating the same object.  If you are creating a new object it will not see any change to the value.

Comment: This is a good article on how often and when it runs $digest:  http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/